# Adding an empty column to a CSV file with Miller

Tags: csv-simple, miller

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
0
1
2
3
```

I'd like to use Miller to append an empty column `x` to every row so that the output file looks like this:

```
0,x
1,
2,
3,
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the `put` verb:

```
$ seq 0 3 | mlr --csv put '$x=""'
0,x
1,
2,
3,
```